# Discord.js/Mongodb How to update all database values

Tags: mongodb, discord.js, robo3t

I am currently creating an economy bot for Discord, and i have a problem i don't know how to solve:

All users have a salary, that will be set with a command. I want to create a command that can update all users account with the set salary amount.
Instead of having to ping a specific user, how could i make it that the command would update values of all found users in the MongoDB Database?

Here is current code:

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
module.exports = {
    name: 'pay',
    aliases: [],
    permissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
    description: "pay users their salary",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord, profileData) {
        const amount = profileData.pay;
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();

    try{

        await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate({
                userID: target.id,
        }, {
            $inc: {
                bank: amount,
            },
        }
        );

        return message.channel.send(`Users have been paid.`);
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
},
};
```

As you can see, currently its waiting for the user to ping a user. But i would want it to just update all found users inside the Database without needing to specify who it is.

I would really appereciate help!

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has the method `updateMany`, docs found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/), which updates all documents if the query is set to an empty object.  So, just try:

```
await profileModel.updateMany({}, {
            $inc: {
                bank: amount,
            },
        }
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It almost solved my problem. 

Only problem left is, that it updates all users with the same amount.
Person 1 has an account with 3000 coins. His set salary is 3000.
Person 2 has an account with 3000 coins. His set salary is 2500. 
When i run command "pay", it updates both accounts with the 3000, while person 2 should actually receive 2500. So how could i specify it to check everyone's own set pay amount?